# What is the difference between Vandalism and Causes Harm while reviewing an edit?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I recently started reviewing proposed edits and have come across a few like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13629997).

The proposed edit changes the title in order to misspell the first word. I've marked these kind of proposed edits as vandalism, however on this post I noticed that another reviewer had marked it as causing harm.

When should I mark a proposed edit as vandalism vs causing harm?

Comment: Yeah "causes harm" isn't a great label for a "custom" or "other" reason IMO.

Comment: Last february, I already posted a feature request on MSE to [rename "causes harm" to "other"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274093/edit-reject-reasons-replace-causes-harm-with-other).

Comment: To me this looks like the editor was in the wrong input-field when he tried to add the [tag:sorting]-tag but didn't notice that he had changed the title.

Comment: Vandalism is harmful to *the post*, but I imagine that "causes harm" means harm to *humans*. Doxxing is an example of causing harm via the internet. (I haven't looked at this specific example, so I don't know if it's a good use of the label.)

Comment: "Vandalism" is another word for "come on, not *another* audit".

Comment: @JasonC Haha, true! But it also often happens as a rage-quit - when an asker wants to leave the site, and tries to deface the answers they received.

Comment: "Harm" means it's bad. "Vandalism" means it's deliberately bad.

Answer (score 12):

"Spam or vandalism" means just that: the edit is meant to vandalize the post, or to introduce spam.

If a reviewer chooses this option, and apparently if an editor has been identified by the system as a possible spammer, subsequent reviewers will see a warning: "Our system has identified this edit as possible spam. Please review carefully."

It is likely that if an editor gets a lot of edits rejected with the "spam or vandalism" reason, the moderators will be warned, or edit bans and IP blocks may activate.

By contrast, "Causes harm" just allows the reviewer to give a customized reject reason. It will not leave a mark against the editor beyond having a reject vote on their edit.

In the case of this particular edit suggestion, it is wrong and should be rejected. Or you may choose to either "Reject & Edit" or "Improve", and fix the issues yourself. However, I don't think this particular edit was *deliberately* destructive, so rejecting it as "Spam or vandalism" is a bit harsh. [Pang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1402846/pang), who used the "causes harm" option, actually did the editor a favor by explaining what was wrong.

Comment: *It is likely that if an editor's post gets enough "spam or vandalism" rejections, the moderators will be warned, or edit bans and IP blocks may activate.* Any source for this? The first sentence of [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109272/295232) seems to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @Glorfindel No source, or I would have stated it as a fact, not as "is likely". Grace Note referred to automatic flags. However. If I understand that answer right, a single rejection as spam won't raise flags, but a pattern of them will cause the system to raise an alert. Edited my answer accordingly.We have had spammers try to edit their spam in as many posts as they could. It's a safe bet that SE has some defenses against that.

Comment: [*"We track data on edits rejected with that reason ... which is used to help protect against future spam"* - Grace Note♦ - Jul 2 2014](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234954/204869)